# How to Get stdClass object with in stdClass Object value?

Tags: stdclass

```
stdClass Object ( [PageNumber] => 0 [EntriesPerPage] => 0 [TotalEntries] => 643 [TotalPages] => 0 [Data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [OrderId] => 521990a8-365d-43cd-aa6d-e4c54636c3e9 [NumOrderId] => 687215 [GeneralInfo] => stdClass Object ( [Status] => 1 [LabelPrinted] => [LabelError] => [InvoicePrinted] => [PickListPrinted] => [Notes] => 0 [PartShipped] => [Marker] => 0 [ReferenceNum] => C Discount_1701210529XQFC0 [SecondaryReference] => C Discount_1701210529XQFC0 [ExternalReferenceNum] => C Discount_1701210529XQFC0 [ReceivedDate] => 2017-01-21T05:29:26.063 [Source] => CDISCOUNT [SubSource] => C Discount [HoldOrCancel] => [DespatchByDate] => 2017-02-01T06:08:32.603 [Location] => 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 [NumItems] => 1 ) [ShippingInfo] => stdClass Object ( [Vendor] => DPD [PostalServiceId] => a48ee6be-d857-4c83-880c-47b725430c2c [PostalServiceName] => DPD Expresspak [TotalWeight] => 301 [ItemWeight] => 0 [PackageCategoryId] => 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 [PackageCategory] => Medium Product [PackageTypeId] => [PackageType] => [PostageCost] => 7.99 [PostageCostExTax] => 0 [TrackingNumber] => [ManualAdjust] => )
```

I want to get "ReceivedDate" Value.
Pls Help to get value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo $object_name->data[0]->GeneralInfo->ReceivedDate;//$object_name is name of your object..which gives above result on var_dump()
```

Comment: Its working,But need also [Items] array value in CategoryName

Comment: try `$object_name->data[0]->ShippingInfo->PackageCategory`; for CategoryName.

Comment: "Data": [
    {
      "OrderId": "fd023def-e36f-4615-aaac-71873262670c",
      "NumOrderId": 2,
      "GeneralInfo": {
        "Status": 1,
        "LabelPrinted": true,
        "LabelError": "sample string 3",
      
      },
      "ShippingInfo": {        
        "PackageCategoryId": "254aebf0-22fa-433c-839d-3485b7ead5ea",
        "PackageCategory": "sample string 7",
    
      },    
      "Items": [
        {
       
          "CategoryName": "sample string 9",
          "CompositeAvailablity": 1,
     }]No, I need Items category...

Comment: like this `$object_name->data[0]->items[0]->CategoryName;`